# Update post meta - Custom field does not match meta-key

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, post-meta

I am trying to update my acf with `update-post-meta`:

```
//ga_analytics_settings
update_post_meta($my_post, 'ganalytics_settings', serialize($ganalytics_settings));
```

`$ganalytics_settings` is an array, which I would like to store `serialized` within the field.

[image]

However, I get the following condition is not met(taken from meta.php):

```
function update_metadata($meta_type, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value = '') {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! $meta_type || ! $meta_key || ! is_numeric( $object_id ) ) {
        return false; //I am getting here in, but I do not know why.
    }
```

Any suggestions what I might do wrong?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are serialized by default, so just do

```
update_post_meta($my_post, 'ganalytics_settings', $ganalytics_settings);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

> $meta_value (mixed) (required) The new value of the custom field. A
>   passed array will be serialized into a string.(this should be raw as
>   opposed to sanitized for database queries) Default: None

Also, make sure that `$my_post` is post ID, not the post object.

And, if you want to update ACF field, you should use it's `update_field` function.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/